# Create Agents in ResourcePool with speficied Home Locations

Tags: anylogic

i want to create different agents of type-class -machine- within a **Population of resourcePools** and want to access theese machines from a **population of agents** -machines-. By adding resource units  to the resourcePool[...], the corresponding agents will be added to the Population machines .

```
int r=6;
for (int i =0; i<r-1;i++) 
{
add_resourcePool();
machines(i).IdMachine = (int) tbl_Machinery.getCellNumericValue(1,i+2,1);     //Id             machines(i).IdTechnology = (int) tbl_Machinery.getCellNumericValue(1,i+2,2);  //TechId
machines(i).Technology= tbl_Machinery.getCellStringValue(1,i+2,3);        //Technology
}
```

so in the end i have a population of resource Pools - resourcePool[5]
and a population of machines - machines[5]

So resourcePool(1) shows the resourcePool for machines(1) and so on, through this i have the opportunity to use the functions (e.g. isbusy(), isidle(), ...) of the resourcePool and on the other site there is the option to consider to an unique machine (e.g. machines (1) in resourcePool(1)).

By adding theese machines to the resourcePool, the machines will be positioned all on the same node.

Is there an opportunity to set a specific Node/Coordinate for every resourcePool(i), so the machines will be in different locations on my shopfloor?

I tryed something like:

```
resourcePool(i).setHomeLocation(node1);
```

I already know, that i can change the location of the resource unit by using the setHomeLocation(...) function. But the machines just positiones after they are already used by an agent (e.g. Part in on my shopfloor). So if it is possible to refresh the position of the resource Units just after changing the homelocation, my problem will be solved i think.

```
machine unit = (machine)resourcePool(0).iterator().next();
unit.setHomeLocation(nodeM2);
```